# Why do I need a primary template in this case of variadic non type template arguments?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++20, non-type-template-parameter

I tried to get this code to compile, it did not.

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T, int head_size, int... tail_sizes>
struct yarray<T, head_size, tail_sizes...> : public  std::conditional_t<sizeof...(tail_sizes) == 0, 
    std::array<T, head_size>,
    std::array<yarray<T, tail_sizes...>, head_size>>
{};
```

```
error: 'yarray' is not a class template
    4 | struct yarray<T, head_size, tail_sizes...> : public  std::conditional_t<sizeof...(tail_sizes) == 0,
      |        ^~~~~~
```

Then an expert friend of mine told me to define primary template and it [works](https://godbolt.org/z/az1T1MPq1).

```
// primary template
template<typename T, int... tail_sizes>
struct yarray{};
```

My question is why is this needed?
From what I can see "recursion" never hits the empty variadic pack case, so my original code has all the "information" needed.

Is it just "language rules demand it", or is there another reason why this is required?

Comment: You need a primary template, period. There are no specializations without a primary.

Comment: You wrote a template specialisation, but a specialisation of what template exactly? Does it have default template parameters? Does it have a parameter pack? Perhaps more than one pack? How should the compiler know? Before you say "oh but in this case it doesn't need to know" write down *all* the cases when there is no need to know.

Comment: I believe, even `template<typename T, int... tail_sizes> struct yarray;` should work and would prevent that the non-specialized template can be used accidentally. (I already used that when writing traits. I didn't need parameter packs but I would wonder if this would change anything.)

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem I was hoping that it would be interpreted as primary template that "requires" at least 1 integer provided(since I have int head_size, int... tail_sizes so for cases when tail_sizes sizeof... is 0 you still need head_size). But you make a valid point. It is probably too complicated to standardize for saving me 3 lines of code...

Comment: You *do* form `yarray<T>` in the last step of the recursion—the fact that it’s used only as a template argument to a class template (`std::conditional`) that does nothing with it is relevant only in that it need not be *complete*.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there is a hack to make *something like this* [work](https://godbolt.org/z/M34GPT58G), friend of mine helped me get this hack/workaround.

```
constexpr int terminate = 123456789;

template<typename T, int head_size, int tail_head=terminate, int... tail_sizes>
struct yyarray:
    public  std::conditional_t<tail_head == terminate, 
    std::array<T, head_size>,
    std::array<yyarray<T, tail_head, tail_sizes...>, head_size>>
{};
```

**BUT** as comments say answer to my original question is simply no, you can not have template specialization, even when it is "obvious" how it should behave.